# An OleDbParameter with ParameterName is not contained by this OleDbParameterCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Very simple form like a dozen others I've made for internal tools, but this one kicks back the error "An OleDbParameter with ParameterName '@lookup' is not contained by this OleDbParameterCollection."

The only difference, and it's probably the key to this, but I'm afraid I don't know the answer, is the connection string. I have been using a SQL 2008 server on a Windows 2008 R2 server so I my connection string has been easily configured in my Visual Studio 2008 like below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatasourceName" connectionString="server=servername;database=databasename;user=username;password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

However, I'm still using VS 2008 but I'm connecting to a SQL 2012 server for my datasource so I had to change the connection string to:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="server2012name" connectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=ServerName;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User ID=userid;Initial Catalog=catalog"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

So since I've never seen this error, I wonder if the code I'm using does not work with an oledb connection for some reason. The offending piece of code is in the codebehind:

```
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@lookup"].Value = lookup.Text.ToString();

}
```

Here is the ASPX code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Beneficiary First Name] AS firstname
                            ,[Beneficiary Last Name] AS lastname
                            ,[Beneficiary Date of Birth] AS dob
                            ,[Address Line 1] AS [address]
                            ,[Beneficiary Encounter Date] AS encdate
                            ,[Beneficiary Data Sharing Preference Code] AS shareprefcode
                            ,[Beneficiary Data Sharing Decision Mechanism Code] AS decmechcode
                            ,[Beneficiary Alcohol and Drug Treatment Data Sharing Mechanism Co] AS damechcode
                            ,[MRN]
                            ,[Beneficiary HICN] AS hicn
                       FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
                       WHERE [MRN] = @lookup"

           onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"
           >
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="lookup" />
         </SelectParameters>
         </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Do I need some other assembly included? Do I use a different command to add that parameter?

I've Googled this for hours and read through what I found, but none of it seemed to pertain to this. If I commend this e.Command.Parameters line out, the error goes away, but the query won't return anything.

Thanks so much for any guidance.

EDIT
Unfortunately, it looks like this one's going to go unanswered. I'll add a little more here in case someone who knows what this is all about comes along.

I've been reading all about OleDbParameters and that seems to be roughly the right track. I've changed the codebehind to about 50 variations of this:

```
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    OleDbParameter fnParam = new OleDbParameter("@lookup", OleDbType.VarChar, 20);
    fnParam.Value = lookup.Text;
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(fnParam);
}
```

And I have managed to move past the original error. I've changed the ASPX to remove the parameter declaration, no go. I've changed the parameter in the SQL query to a question mark, no go. At this point, I get no error or message of any kind. In my SQL Profiler trace, it's not hitting the SQL server at all. It's just not doing anything.

In some of my variations, it actually gave me errors for data type mismatches, but I never could figure out how to alter the textbox value to be the right kind of data type for the OleDbType.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. That command Parameters collection doesn't have the OleDbParameter named @lookup. Probably the problem lies in the ASPX code that defines the SqlDataSource1 If you could add that markup to your question...

Comment: What is the Select Command for that data source?

Comment: Do OleDb parameters have names? Aren't they just placeholders (?)?

Comment: The lookup parameter is in the ASPX. I'll post the code when I'm back at work, but as I mentioned, I've done this many times and never had a problem. In the SqlDatasource1, the select statement is a very basic SELECT with a WHERE [MRN] = @lookup. Then in the select parameters, there is only one parameter, lookup. I certainly do wish this error message was clear or at least so to me. I have many small web apps just like this I've used for comparison, and the only difference they have is in the connection string. Thanks all of you for your input either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updates, I suspect you are very close to doing the correct thing. The main problem you have is that you are using the OLE DB provider, which doesn't support named parameters in its queries. Instead, you have to use positional paramters, and specify them explicitly, in the correct order, as part of the appropriate parameters collection in ASP.

It should look something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyString %>" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT list_of_columns
                   FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
                   WHERE column = ?"
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="lookup" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>


protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@lookup"].Value = 1234;
}
```

Note a few things:

- The parameter in the query is just a '?'. These are positional: they are replaced in order by the parameters you define later.
- The `SelectParameters` collection has the same number of entries, in the same order, as the query has '?' placeholders. In this case, there's just one, but if you had multiple parameters you'd define them in order. If you want to use the same value multiple times, you still need to specify multiple parameters and set them all individually.
- The name you use to look up the parameter in the collection is the name you give it in the `SelectParameters` collection, with an "@" appended.
- As far as I know, you **must** specify the correct parameter type when you do this. I always have, at least, and it's "worked for me".

It looks like, at some point, you tried something like this, but without seeing every iteration of code you tried, I can't be sure. At any rate, this is how OLE DB parameterized queries work, so this should be what you need. If not, please update your question with the results of trying this out.

For more information, see:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/vstudio/z72eefad(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/vstudio/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. This info has been slowly making its way through my thick skull. Yes, I did try something like this at some point, but I had gotten so frustrated I was trying anything I could think of so there's no telling what detail I might have overlooked. I do believe I was very close, and I'm going to come back to this and figure it out. I ran out of time and had to change to a previous server so I could use my old code and get it done quickly. And of course it works fine with SQLParameters. Again, thank you. I'm going to mark this as the answer.